# How to delete multiple url params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

There is a problem with deleting several string parameters. Only the last parameter is being deleted now.

**upd**: I did not specify that I wanted to achieve the ability to remove specific parameter values

this code does not work correctly:

```
const updateFiltersSearchParams = (paramKey, newValue) => {
    const isParamExist = searchParams.getAll(paramKey).includes(newValue);

    if (!isParamExist) {
      searchParams.append(paramKey, newValue);
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    } else {
      const updatedSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(
        [...searchParams].filter(
          ([key, value]) => key !== paramKey || value !== newValue
        )
      );
      setSearchParams(updatedSearchParams);
    }
  };

const handleDeleteParams = () => {
    [...checkboxParams].forEach((param) => {
      updateFiltersSearchParams("selected", param);
    });
  };
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-noether-wm6ud?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Rapidly setting state in a `forEach` without basing the change on the state previous value, can result in changes appearing to be skipped.

Comment: @DBS How then can I take into account the previous values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem by modifying the function like this

```
const toggleSearchParams = (params) => {
    const newSearchParams = [...searchParams];

    for (const prevParam of params) {
      const index = newSearchParams.findIndex(
        (newParam) =>
          prevParam[0] === newParam[0] && prevParam[1] === newParam[1]
      );

      if (index === -1) {
        newSearchParams.push(prevParam);
      } else {
        newSearchParams.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }

    setSearchParams(new URLSearchParams(newSearchParams));
  };

  const handleChangeCheckBoxValue = (e) => {
    toggleSearchParams([["selected", e.target.value]]);
  };

  const handleDeleteParams = () => {
    toggleSearchParams(checkboxParams.map((param) => ["selected", param]));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete ***only** the `selected` (*or any specific queryString key*) queryString parameters you can use the `delete` method of the `URLSearchParams` object, then enqueue the params URL update.

```
const handleDeleteParams = (key) => {
  searchParams.delete(key);
  setSearchParams(searchParams);
};
```

...

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => handleDeleteParams("selected")}>
  Clear all "selected" params
</button>
```

[image: Edit how-to-delete-multiple-url-params]

Answer (score 0):

change your `handleDeleteParams` function with this

```js
const handleDeleteParams = () => {
  setSearchParams([]);
};
```

Comment: This option will not work. There may be other parameters or you need to exclude specific values

Comment: @v.zdorovcev This was close to the solution I was going to propose, but maybe you should update your question to include ***all*** relevant details, requirements, and restrictions.